# Storm : How to get a sentiment indicator with Trident and a Redis State?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, apache-storm, trident

I am trying to create a sentiment indicator with a Redis state. Here is my code:

```
TweetSpout twitterSpout = new TweetSpout();
Stream textStream = topology.newStream("tweetSpout", twitterSpout);
        textStream.each(new Fields("texto"), new TwitterSentimentClassifier(), new Fields("sentiment","date"))
       .each(new Fields("sentiment","date"),new Union(), new Fields("key"))
       .groupBy(new Fields("key"))
       .persistentAggregate(state, new Count(), new Fields("count"))
       .parallelismHint(6);
```

Basically, I receive a tweet, and I classify the tweet with the `TwitterSentimentClassifier` function into positive or negative, and I obtain the date, too. Then, the `Union` function concatenate the feeling and the date (e.g. `positive2014.15.05`), in order to have one key (I'm doing this because Trident-Redis only allow one key). Next, Trident groups by the key. Finally, `.persistentAggregate` persists the counts per keys in a Redis database. This works fine.

But now, I want to show this indicator in a `node.js` application connected with Redis.

**Indicator today = Number of tweets negatives today /Total of tweets today**

So, I was wondering:

- Should I use a DRCP call with a state query?
- Do i have to use another persistent aggregator in order to store the indicator value?
- Do I have to create a Trident function to store the indicator value in a Redis db?
- I am going to use `Node.js`, `socket.io`, `express` and `d3.js` for the visualization. Can I use a normal division operation in Javascript with my actual Redis state?